# How to connect to mysql using java?

Tags: java, mysql

i'm want to store emails from Gmail into my mysql database.
i found Inboxreader with google but the part for connection to mysql is not working.
the username, database name, password is correct.

can anyone help me.
Thank you.

here is the part of the code

```
{
            Properties details= new Properties();
            details.load(new FileInputStream("details.properties"));
            String userName = details.getProperty("root");
            String password = details.getProperty("password");
            String url = details.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            System.out.println ("Database connection established");
            PreparedStatement st= conn.prepareStatement("insert into 'Email_list' values(?)");
            for(String mail:mails)
            {
            try{
                  st.setString(1, mail);
                  st.execute();
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
```

Here is the error code:

```
Cannot connect to database server
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
Reading:23
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:554)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at inboxreader.InboxReader.connecttoMySql(InboxReader.java:181)
    at inboxreader.InboxReader.Start(InboxReader.java:82)
    at inboxreader.InboxReader.main(InboxReader.java:34)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
String url = details.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
```

You are getting a `null` value in `url`. That's because there is no property called `jdbc:mysql://localhost/test` in your properties file.

You have two options. One would be using `url` directly with something like:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
```

The other option would be having a correctly set up property in `details.properties`:

```
# hello, I am details.properties file
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
```

Then, in your Java code you would read `url` from property like this:

```
String url = details.getProperty("jdbc.url"); // note that we're changing property name
```

Comment: @Pacific - there's also no reason to tie your Java code to MySQL. Since you already have `details.properties` put in something like `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://etc` and `jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` then you can do `Class.forName(details.getProperty("jdbc.driver"))`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get the value of a property from `details` like this:

```
String url = details.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
```

It seems to me that the name of the property there is actually your value.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir Pablo, Sergio and fivedigit

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you don't have one key "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" in your properties file. Let's say that details.properties have this content:

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
```

So your code should be

```
String url = details.getProperty("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that your property key ha issue  :

```
 String url = details.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
```

You should first validate that weather you have correct key or not

```
 if (details.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test") != null || 
    details.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test").trim().length > 0){
       url =details.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
 }else{
 return new Exception("Wrong property key");
 }
```

Comment: Now my code is working but i made a mistake i know the database name is test, the table name is Email_list but when i go to mysql the table is Email_list is empty.

Comment: "when i go to mysql the table is Email_list is empty" means when you are using the mysql ide? or when you establish the connection?,